# Should i run Rails behind Apache/nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am slowly approaching deployment of a company internal Rails application, and am trying to find out whether i should be running the application server behind Apache/nginx in production.

Currently thin is being used as the Application server, but i keep reading about how it may be unfit for use in a production environment on its own.

For a application on a on-site dedicated server that will never be accessed by more than 10 users at any given time, what should i be looking at? Phusion Passenger? Unicorn? Or am i going to be fine with just thin?